# What is the equivalent of Puppet exec' owner in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

**Ansible version**

```
user@server:/home$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.1.0
```

In Puppet:

```
exec { 'run gulp as www-data':
  command     => '/usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp'
  cwd         => '/var/www'
  user        => 'www-data'
}
```

and this works as well:

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp
```

but when

```
- command: /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}"
  become: www-data
```

is used in ansible, it results in:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp"], 
"delta": "0:00:00.631959", "end": "2016-09-15 09:57:41.167507", ...
```

If

```
- command: /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}"
```

is run the gulp command is executed as the root user, while it should be run as `www-data`.

**Question**

How should `sudo -u www-data /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp` be translated in Ansible so that the outcome it the same when it is run in Puppet and in Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set [`become_user`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#directives):

```
- name: run gulp
  command: /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_dir }}"
  become: True
  become_user: www-data
```

Take a look at the example in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html):

```
- name: Run a command as the apache user
  command: somecommand
  become: true
  become_user: apache
```

Comment: `Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user`

Comment: That seems to be another issue. Look at [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646880/ansible-2-1-0-using-become-become-user-fails-to-set-permissions-on-temp-file)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't say which version of Ansible you're using. In 2.x you can do :

```
- name: run gulp
  remote_user: www-data
  command: /usr/local/lib/npm/bin/gulp
```

Comment: The issue persists. When `www-data2` is defined ansible does not complain (`www-data2` does not exist). It looks like that the `remote_user` option is ignored or something

Answer (score 0):

Henrik Pingel is correct also with his hint to the limitations of some system ,
since  www-data is not a full user on most systems.

But if sudo workd manually you can try to specify in the ansible_become_method variable for a host in the inventory what method ansible should use to become another user:

```
ansible_become_method=sudo
```

or

```
ansible_become_method=su
```

Maybe this could be enough on your specific system instead of some more complicated spteps refered to in the link from Henrik's comment. If not however then I don't see any way around it or maybe even create another new users and reconfigure your webserver / webscripting interpreter to use this new full user instead of www-data, this is what i have been doing to be able to login over ssh and really work as the same user than the webscripts do.